# populating values of a dictionary with lists in python csv package

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, nested

I have a CSV file of sat scores per state. The file has one state's data(state_name, rate, math, verbal) per one row of the CSV. I have created a dictionary with key values of state, rate, math, verbal with the code below:

```
with open('../sat_scores.csv', mode='r') as f:
    sat = {}
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for item in row:
            sat[item]=[]
        break
```

now I to fill the columns with the remaining CSV. The dictionary format for data will be the column names as the key, and the data under each column as the values. I also need to make string numeric columns Rate, Math, and Verbal into floats. I have gotten this far:

```
    for row in reader:
        for item, key in (row, sat.keys()):
            if key == 'State':
                sat[key].append(item)
                print(sat)
            else:
                new_item = float(item)
                sat[key].append(new_item)
                print(sat)
```

I cannot figure out how to loop through both the keys of sat dictionary and the items in row simultaneously. Help, please?

Comment: sorry for the edits I.ve been staring at this for a while now.

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically name your properties based upon the first row of the csv? Or do you already know which columns you're interested in by name?

Comment: Great question, ideally dynamically, I could define a function and make it more global but for this, I know the keys by name

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the order of the header fields:

```
reader = csv.reader(f)
header = next(reader)
for row in reader:
    for name, value in zip(header, row):
        print(name, value)
```

You don't really need to do that yourself though, you can use [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) to get a dictionary per row, with keys taken from the first line:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(f)
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```